# ViewDidLoad and WillHideViewController Not Called When Use UINavigationController as Child of UISplitViewController on iOS13

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ios13

I have an apps with `UISplitViewController` as Root View, but for children of this view I use `UINavigationController`.
Although Master and Detail View is `UIViewController`, but I added this to `UINavigationController` before I set as Child of `UISplitViewController`, I did this because I need `Title` and `UIBarButton`, and also because I share this view for iPad and iPhone.

So this the snippet of my code:

```
MasterView _masterView = new MasterView;
UINavigationController _masterViewNavigation = new UINavigationController(_masterView);

DetailView _detailView = new DetailView;
UINavigationController _detailView Navigation = new UINavigationController(_detailView);

_splitView.ViewController = new UIViewController[]{_masterView, _detailView};
```

Everything was working before iOS 13. But when I run on iOS 13, `ViewDidLoad` of `_masterView` wasn’t called. While I need this to change image view on `_masterView` when the user makes changes on `_detailView`, although `_masterView` not shown.

Also `WillHideViewController` is not called, while I need this to add `UIBarButtonItem` on `_detailView` to show and hide `_masterView`.

Can you help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with iOS 13 Split view controller using IB. If you have navigation controller embedded to Master/Detail view controller it just loads the navigation controller.

To fix that issue create a custom class from UISplitViewController and assign that to your splitviewcontroller in storyboard and programatically add Navigation controller and masterViewcontroller to that UISplitViewController. That should load your view properly. This code goes in the viewdidload or willappear of the UISplitviewcontroller class.
Sample code. in Obj c

```
    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master];
    UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tableViewNavigationController,navC, nil];
```

This fixed my issue , Had similar issue after iOS13. Hope that help !